# How can I make a taller div wrap around the shorter div on the bottom of the shorter div?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have this test page: 
http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem_dev.php?problem_id=225

and I am trying to have the small square ad appear on the left below the person't name. And have the text appear on the right of it.

But when the ad ends, I want to make it so that the body of the text extends to the area below the ad.  Is that possible to accomplish with the layout I have on that page currently?

What would I have to adjust?

Thanks!

ps - I know I am using inline css, but its just for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this div `<div style="float: left; width: 410px;">` that contains the text a value of `display:inline;` only, so you want to remove the float and width properties.

Also, you have specified a height on the `<ins>` tags you can change that to `height:auto;`

Comment: thanks - just tried it and still does not wrap. Any idea what might still be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You still have the width and float properties, remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many divs in there. An image with float: left on it and then just add in the text next to it. It will naturally start wrapping under the image then.

Comment: I am not trying to wrap around the image with the persons avatar. I am trying to wrap the description text with the google ad.  How do I do that?